# What is the default my.cnf on debian's mariadb server?

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf, debian

I'm trying to set `default-time-zone` on mariadb server

`Server version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10`

To do such things, in mysql, I used to simply modify `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but here I have a jungle of config files:

```
/etc/mysql
├── conf.d
│   ├── mysql.cnf
│   └── mysqldump.cnf
├── debian.cnf
├── debian-start
├── mariadb.cnf
├── mariadb.conf.d
│   ├── 50-client.cnf
│   ├── 50-mysql-clients.cnf
│   ├── 50-mysqld_safe.cnf
│   └── 50-server.cnf
├── my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
└── my.cnf.fallback
```

And `my.cnf` only contains this cryptic instructions:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

So I'm wondering what is the relevant config file to make the changes?

Comment: Often the config files contain examples that are just commented out. If you're lucky `grep -rl "default-time-zone" /etc/mysql` spits out the one where `default-time-zone` is supposed to be handled.

Comment: @stickybit I tried that befor posting this question. The command returns nothing.  edded up putting it in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` like this `[mysqld]
default_time_zone='+01:00'` , restrted the server and it worked.

Comment: Hmm, coming to think of it, you could also try to create a new file in oe of the `*.d` directories with your custom settings. That should be included in the final conf. And that way an update cannot overwrite the settings you made in some of the files shipped out of the box. (It may also be that `apt` (if you used a package for installation and didn't compile it yourself or similar) recognizes such a conflict and tells you but that's the safer way I guess.)